# when should an ActiveRecord transaction be used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What is considered "best practice" or the general rule of thumb for when something should be wrapped in a transaction block?

Is it primarily just when you are going to be performing actions on a collection of things, and you want to rollback if something breaks?  Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def mark_all_posts_as_read!
    transaction do
      posts.find_each { |p| p.update_attribute(:read, true) }
    end 
  end
end
```

Are there other scenarios where it would be beneficial to perform things inside a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that qualifies as a great use for a transaction: generally, I would only use a transaction in a model if the state of one object depended on the state of another object. If either object's state is incorrect, then I don't want either to be committed.

The classic example, of course, is bank accounts. If you're transferring money from one account to another, you don't want to add it to the receiving account, save, and then debit it from the sending account. If any part of that goes wrong then money has just vanished, and you will have some pretty angry customers. Doing both parts in one transaction ensures that if an error occurs, neither will have committed anything to the database.

The [ActiveRecord Transaction Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) does a surprisingly good job of discussing the how and why of using transactions... and there's always the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) if you want more information as well.

Comment: I use transactions in rake tasks too. I collect a lot of data in bulk from an API and then do a transaction block around the `create` task to speed up the insertion... only one connection is used for the insert commands rather than opening and closing a connection per task.